# Postback from multiple DropDownList working but not refreshing in page

Tags: c#, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a razor page which contains a for loop which iterates over a list of User objects.

Each repetion of the loop contains a dropdownlist:-

```
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="SetUserStatuses">Update Statuses</button>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserList.Count; i++)
{
    @Model.UserList[i].UserAccountStatusId
    @Html.DropDownList("UserAccountStatusId", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserAccountStatus)).Cast<UserAccountStatus>().Select
(v => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = v.GetDescription(),
    Value = (Convert.ToInt32(v)).ToString()
}), "Value", "Text", Model.UserList[i].UserAccountStatusId))

@Html.Hidden("UserId", Model.UserList[i].UserId)
```

The pagehandler is just:-

```
public void OnPostSetUserStatuses(int[] UserId, int[] UserAccountStatusId)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < UserId.Length; i++)
    {
      userService.SetUserStatus(UserId[i], UserAccountStatusId[i]);
    }
    var userList = userService.GetUsers();
    UserList = userList;
    return Page();
}
```

The model is defined as such:-

```
public List<User> UserList { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public int[] UserAccountStatusId { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public int[] UserId { get; set; }
```

So when I post the submit, the page handler is fired, and the db is updated and the new values are returned to the model within UserList.

Additionally, the line which says:-

```
@Model.UserList[i].UserAccountStatusId
```

is shown with the correct value.

However, the dropdownlist is not refreshed with the correct selected value. I think the problem is that I have multiple dropdowns and there seems to be some binding issue going on which I cannot for the life of me fathom out.

Can someone help please.

Comment: his question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use DropDownListFor

`````
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.UserAccountStatusId[i],
                       ...., @Model.UserAccountStatusId[i])
````
`````

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but if I change it to @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserList[i].UserAccountStatusId, in the page handler, the int[] UserAccountStatusId has a length of 0

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Model.UserList[i].UserAccountStatusId shows the correct updated value but the corresponding option in the dropdownlist is not selected